# How to go from Simulink to embedded fixed-point DSP processor?

Tags: c, software, embedded-systems, matlab

A library of audio algorithms is modeled, tested and verified in **Simulink** (graphical block diagramming tool). It needs to go from this existing Simulink models down to a multiple **embedded platforms** (floating and fixed-point DSP processors: Qualcomm, Tensilica, ARM, etc).

Several workflows are considered:

```
1) Simulink diagram -> Matlab code -> generic C floating point -> C embedded platform 1
                                                               -> C embedded platform 2
                                                               -> C embedded platform 3
2) Simulink diagram -> generic C floating point -> C embedded platform 1
                                                -> C embedded platform 2
                                                -> C embedded platform 3
3) Simulink diagram -> C embedded platform 1
                       C embedded platform 2
                       C embedded platform 3
```

The Simulink models keep changing, so versioning and ease of maintenance should be considered.

Which workflow should be preferred?

***Note***: Simulink has a C code generation feature. It can generate both generic and embedded C code (with some of the required embedded platforms supported (ARM), and some not (Tensilica)). Not sure about the quality and usability of the C code!?

Answer (score 1):

The preferred workflow would be a fully automated one where you have high confidence that the generated C code matches the Simulink models and has the required performance characteristics.

A second-best would be a workflow where a single action in Simulink produces an intermediate file (or even C code) that can be fed into an automated process.

With an automated process, a build server can just take the latest Simulink models and create the binaries that can be put on the embedded processors. Any manual step in between means an additional set of files that need to be archived and can be forgotten to be updated when the model is changed.

I can't recommend a specific workflow, because I don't know the involved tools well enough, but you should be able to do the evaluation yourself. Take a model that is simple enough that you can either verify the generated C code by hand or that you can easily verify the characteristics in a test setup and then just try each of the workflows. If you want more confidence, repeat with some other models, or introduce changes that would show up clearly in the test results. As these are demo/test models, such changes do not need to show only desired effects for production.